# Install contextify on Windows 7 Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 2

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, npm, contextify

This is what I got when running `npm install contextify`

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/contextify
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/contextify
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings

> contextify@0.1.3 install C:\node_modules\myfolder\node_modules\contextify
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\node_modules\myfolder\node_modules\contextify>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_
modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebui
ld
python: can't open file 'C:\Users\Username\.node-gyp\0.8.16\tools\gyp\gyp': [Errn
o 2] No such file or directory
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_module
s\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:395:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:99:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process._handle.onexit (child_process.js:678:10)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\node_modules\myfolder\node_modules\contextify
gyp ERR! node -v v0.8.16
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.7.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! contextify@0.1.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! `cmd "/c" "node-gyp rebuild"` failed with 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the contextify@0.1.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the contextify package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls contextify
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "contextify"
npm ERR! cwd C:\node_modules\myfolder
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.16
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.69
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\node_modules\myfolder\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I have node x64 v0.8.16 and node-gyp v0.8.1

I had Python 2.7.3, .Net Framework 4, Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express, Windows 7 64-bit SDK and Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Service Pack 1 Compiler.

I already restarted my PC. What did I miss?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try install node-gyp

```
npm install -g node-gyp
```

Also what version of python do you have installed I believe you need 2.7